# How to transform this system to $\dot{X}=AX+F$ form and find A, F matrices?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How to transform this system to $\dot{X}=AX+F$ form and find A, F matrices?
$$
a)\ddot{x}+\dot{x}=x-y+t+sint$$
$$\ddot{y}+\dot{y}=x+y+e^t+t^2$$
$$
b)\dddot{x}+\dot{x}+2x=t$$
$$\dddot{y}-\dot{y}-2y=t^2$$

my tryings are :
$x_1=x\\x_2=\dot{x_1}=\dot{x}\\x_3=y\\x_4=\dot{x_3}=\dot{y}\\ \\$

then; $\dot{x_1}=x_2\\\dot{x_2}=x_1-x_3+t+sint-x_2\\\dot{x_3}=x_4\\\dot{x_4}=x_1-x_4+x_3+e^t+t^2$

and
$\dot{X}=$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
     \dot{x_1}\\
    \dot{x_2} \\
    \dot{x_3}\\
\dot{x_4}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$=$
    \begin{pmatrix}
     0&1&0&0\\
    1&0&-1&0 \\
    0&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&-1\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
     x_1\\
    x_2 \\
    x_3\\
x_4\\
    \end{pmatrix}$+$
    \begin{pmatrix}
     0\\
    t+sint \\
    0\\
e^t+t^2\\
    \end{pmatrix}$

is it true like this way? If it is, for the second question do I need to find $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$ and therefor 6x6  matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. You just introduce new variables, corresponding to derivatives of the existente ones, to prevent the occurence of derivatives with order other than one.